# Can't add CefSharp to my toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, cefsharp

I'm currently trying to add CefSharp to my tools so that I can drag and drop a webbrowser onto my form.

I installed CefSharp via NuGet in Visual Studio 2013.

I then right-clicked the tools section and selected "Choose Items"

In the ".NET Framework Components" I selected browse and click on CefSharp.wpf.dll

I then get this error

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wDAAabB.png]

**How can I add the CefSharp browser to my toolbox in Visual Studio 2013?**

Comment: Make sure you configuration manager isn't set to `AnyCPU` per the [read me](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/NuGet/Readme.txt)

Comment: @PhilWalton http://i.imgur.com/YJzQzyy.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not supported, see this FAQ item: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Wpf_designer

You have to edit the small bit of XAML that's needed by hand in Visual Studio.

Apart from the projects `MinimalExample` repository on GitHub there is also a tutorial taking you through the initial steps at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part

Comment: Then how can I actually use it?

Comment: Where can I find the MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: When you init a WPF project its part of the project. In the source of the tutorial above its at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Tutorial/blob/master/Sample1/Sample1/MainWindow.xaml

Comment: I meant that, I'm supposed to edit my MainWindow.xaml to have that code, where would I find my MainWindow.xaml to edit?

Comment: Ah! Got in front of VS now to be able to guide you. In the XAML Designer Window click the `XAML` tab. You probably have the `Design` tab open *and* with the split pane view minimized.